# How do I fix my Spring Boot application from crashing when running my controller tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I as the title says I have a Spring Boot application that is failing when I run some tests, more specifically the controller tests. The issue came up once I was done adding authentication to the app. I realized the tests for the controllers were not passing, not a single one. When I tried running the debugger, I saw the following error: `"Parameter 0 of constructor in com.league_buddies.backend.security.authentication.AuthenticationFilter required a bean of type 'com.league_buddies.backend.security.jwt.JwtService' that could not be found."`

I have the following class that loads up all the beans my application uses:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userService.findByEmailAddress(username);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(authenticationProvider());
        return providerManager;
    }
}
```

This is my AuthenticationFilter class:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtService jwtService;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String token;
        if (authorization == null || !authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        // JWT tokens start with "Bearer ". We have to remove that part to get the actual token.
        token = authorization.substring("Bearer ".length());
        String username = jwtService.extractSubject(token);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if(jwtService.isTokenValid(token, userDetails)) {
                // This is the recommended way for setting the context by Spring Security.
                SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
                context.setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities()
                ));
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

And lastly this is my JwtService (The privateKey will change don't worry):

```
@Service
public class JwtService {
    // TODO move this to application config level.
    private final String privateKey = "SDGJKHJK35346KHJ4/sdfjkhsdka98dsgd357qjahf2897452381!";
    public String generateToken(String username) {
        return Jwts
                .builder()
                .setSubject(username)
                .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000))
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    private Claims extractClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    public String extractSubject(String token) {
        return extractClaims(token).getSubject();
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaims(token).getExpiration();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(privateKey);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        return extractSubject(token).equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token);
    }
}
```

I believe that by including the annotations that my classes have, Spring Boot should load them and there should be not problems, at least there are no problems when I run the application, it's only when I try to run the tests for the controllers that this happens. Here is a part of one of them if you want to look at it, I'm using MockMvc to call the endpoints etc:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserControllerTest.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    // TODO Make a constant for the API url to avoid writing it over and over.
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private UserService userService;

    private UserController userController;

    @Autowired
    CustomExceptionHandler customExceptionHandler;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private long id;

    private Optional<User> optionalUser;

    private String displayName;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        // Stub user service with mock user repository
        userService = new UserService(userRepository);

        // Start controller with user service that has the mock user repository
        userController = new UserController(userService);

        // Builds a MockMvcBuilder and passes it the CustomExceptionHandler
        // so that it can use it, otherwise it will use the default one Spring Boot
        // comes with.
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController)
                .setControllerAdvice(customExceptionHandler)
                .build();

        id = 1L;
        displayName = "Isolated";
        email = "email@gmail.com";
        password = "pw12345";
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(id);
        user.setDisplayName(displayName);
        user.setEmailAddress(email);
        user.setPassword(password);
        optionalUser = Optional.of(user);
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsWhenUserDoesNotExistInDatabaseWithGivenId() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());

        // Act
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                get(String.format("/api/v1/user/%d", id)).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn().getResponse();

        ApiException apiException = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), ApiException.class);

        // Assert
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals(String.format("User with id: %d was not found.", id), apiException.getMessage());
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsWhenGivenNegativeValueToGetById() throws Exception {
        // Act
        id = -1L;
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mockMvc.perform(
                get(String.format("/api/v1/user/%s", id)).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn().getResponse();
        ApiException apiException = objectMapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), ApiException.class);

        // Assert
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("Id cannot be negative.", apiException.getMessage());
    }
```

I tried setting up different profiles so that I could deactivate spring security during the tests but that didn't seem to work.
I also tried using the annotation @WithMockUser(username = "user1", password = "pwd", roles = "USER") but that's when I realized the tests weren't even running.

Comment: You can add `@Import` to your test for adding additional beans, e.g. `@Import({JwtService.class, YourUserDetailService})`

Comment: Hi @dan1stisonstrike thank you for your response. I tried doing that like this: ```@Import({UserService.class, UserRepository.class, JwtService.class})``` since those are the ones it kept throwing errors for. It gave me a different error so this is good news. The error is something along the lines of  ```"Error creating bean with name 'com.league_buddies.backend.user.UserService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'com.league_buddies.backend.user.UserRepository'"``` any knowledge about this that you can share?

Comment: Your test is weird, you want `@WebMvcTest` but then go into configuring everything yourself. THen what is the purpose of `@WebMvcTest`? Also `@WebMvcTest` will only create web related beans so it will **not** create an instance of your `JwtService` or any other service for that matter. Now as it is required for security you will need that. To fix the last error replace `@Mock` with `@MockBean` and remove the `UserService`/`UserController` creation from your setup method, as well as the manual creation of the `MockMvc` just `@Autowired` it.

Comment: In general using jwts as session tokens is insecure and is the reason why spring does not have a prebuilt implementation for it. You application is now vulnerable for session stealing, cross site scripting attacks and you can not logout the user and your application will be easy to DDoS. Stop using jwts as sessions

Comment: Thanks for that @M.Deinum. I'm new to Spring Security and I was following this one tutorial that implemented JWT tokens and I just sort of followed it. I read the docs from Spring Security but they don't have examples of how to do things so I had to do it this way. I will keep learning and make the changes you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: @Toerktumlare, I had no idea. I'm new to Spring Boot and I just went with it because it's something I've used before (JWT tokens). I will look into what you mentioned and look for a good replacement to what I've done to make my application secure which is definitely my goal. Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you are new you should start with the documentation

Comment: @Toerktumlare that's exactly what I did but the documentation is very complicated for somebody new, and they lack examples that would make it easier to understand. Someone recommended me a book called "Spring Security in Action" so hopefully that helps. Thank you.

Comment: if you think the docs are complicated, then that would be an excellent question to ask us to clarify something in the documentation if it is complicated. i suggest you start reading here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-architecture and then continue here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/architecture.html if you understand these 2 pages you will understand everything else in the docs

Comment: @Toerktumlare I went through those a couple days ago and I did get a good understanding of them. I think what I'm confused or need to learn more about is simply how to implement those things that they mention in the docs. For example Java/Spring Boot has many Interfaces that already have implementations so you don't have to implement your own and so I don't know when to use those, which one is best, etc. I think it's just practice I need though and trial and error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `I'm confused or need to learn more about is simply how to implement those things that they mention in the doc` i dont really get it, they have a chpater that is clearly named `Samples` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/samples.html which linkes to tonnes of samples, and start out with implementing form security https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

Comment: Thank you! @Toerktumlare. You've been very helpful. I fixed my error with one of the comments before yours. Your comments have been helpful by making me think of the tokens and making me realize I need to dig deeper into the docs. Appreciate the help!